# SVN - How to make an Older Revision as the Head Revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

May I please know how to make an older revision in Tortoise SVN Repository as the Head Revision **using Tortoise SVN in Windows**? I can't see the context menu "Revert to this revision" in the Log Dialog.

Comment: A quick search for "tortoise svn revert" using Google shows a lot of useful results. Did you try searching there?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try [rolling back](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html)?

[image]

Comment: @ phasetwenty - Thanks for your answer. However, I am unable to see these menus - "Revert to this revision" and "Revert changes from this revision" when I right click on any revision in the Log Dialog. May I request you to please help me how to get these options?

Comment: @FengZhang comments "You need to go to the physical folder, highlight and right click to see these options."

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect.
"Revert from" reverts the selected version's changes only.
"Revert to" will only revert your working copy. If you make changes after reversion, the next commit will fail with "files out of date", asking to update first. If you update, your working copy is back again to the latest actual. SVN is as intuitive or efficient as a dried bat carcass stuck in my front grille.